# How to draw and save 3D model in Qt from an array of 3d points?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, drawing

In my program I have an array of points with X; Y; Z coordinates. I need to be able to draw 3d model according to coordinates from this points and save it in file.

And I'm stuck. Task seems to be not that difficult, it looks like I just need some common 3d format so I can put this coordinates and save it as some 3d models. And then load using QtOpenGL. But I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has a [tutorial](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-quick3d-snapshot/qt3d-penguin.html) on importing and displaying 3ds models. It's not exactly what you wanted, since it does not operate with array of 3d point coordinates, but how about editing the model in Maya/Blender/anything else that can export 3ds and loading it this way? Moreover (I haven't tried this, but at least according to the documentation it seems a viable approach), you can access the model through     [QGLAbstractScene::mainNode()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-quick3d-snapshot/qglabstractscene.html#mainNode), then obtain the geometry of the mesh through [QGLSceneNode::geometry()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-quick3d-snapshot/qglscenenode.html#geometry) and then edit the vertices of [QGeometryData](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-quick3d-snapshot/qgeometrydata.html) instance. It could also be possible to construct a new geometry instace from your point array and render it, but I can't provide a snippet for that, you should look at the documentation.